# left rear control knob on our GE Range JBP30CB1CC gets very hot after 10-15 minutes when that burner is turned on

Tags: switch, stove

left rear control knob on our GE Range JBP30CB1CC gets very hot after 10-15 minutes when that burner is turned on. I'm assuming the surface element switch for that burner needs replacing.

Comment: It seems something is wrong. Make a service call.

Comment: what is your question? ... what is `surface element switch`?

Comment: Just turned on the rear large burner (left) on highest heat on our GE JSP31G OP1WH, bought new by us 30 years ago. This has the coil burner elements. Knob is not hot or even warm after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three likely possibilities:

- Element

If the element is somehow drawing a lot more power than it should, any controls will have that current flowing through them as well and heat up more than normal. I actually doubt that's the case, so the key question is: Does the element produce a normal amount of heat and cycle normally? (In other words, does it work?)

- Connections

I suspect this is the problem. A bad connection, possibly due to wear & tear, possibly something "broke", possibly due to food/dirt/etc. getting into the controls, can result in a high resistance connection, which will be **hot**.

- Switch

If the switch itself is failing, it may internally produce a high resistance and heat. But I suspect in most cases this would result in a complete failure of the switch.

So the likely answer, assuming the element still seems to basically work, is the wiring connecting the power in/out of the switch. Some disassembly required, as pulling off the knob usually doesn't expose any wires. **Unplug (if plug is accessible) or turn off the breaker first.** Typically you have to take off the front and/or top of the cooktop with multiple screws, etc. Once you have it apart, look for loose connections, corrosion, foreign objects, water damage, etc. If you can't figure it out, post pictures.

Comment: the element appears to be working normally. This is an electric stove and the control knobs are on the control panel at the back, above the stove top. Do you think the problem is between the element control switch and the knob? Should I open the back and remove the switch so that I can see behind the knob?

Comment: The knob is just a piece of plastic or metal stuck on top. I think the problem is the control switch itself or the wiring connecting the control switch to incoming power or to the element - i.e., the wires connected to the switch.

Comment: I now think there is no problem with the knob getting hot. When I first noticed the problem, I had a pot on the front burner but had the back one turned on by mistake, with nothing on that burner. That must be why that knob (as well as the one next to it) got so hot. I just now put a pot of water on that burner and the knob didn't heat up. I feel like such an idiot!

Comment: Don't feel so bad. Stuff happens. It is, IMHO, extremely poor design to have knobs in the back - it means reaching over hot burners to turn something off, as well as the problem you found - the controls can heat up from the burners very easily if not covered. The problem is that the front has the "child access" and "accidental bump" problems. And the manufacturers don't want to put the controls on the surface (as they do with separate cooktops) because that takes away from the limited 24" or 30" wide area for burners.